# Beautiful Soup WebScraping Error - ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

#### Hey there,

***I've seen questions very similar this, however they are usually dealing with tables.***

I am simply trying to scrape information off of the Harry Potter Wiki page, however when simply referencing/attempting to find tags in the html code, it pulls an error saying `ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'`. Here is my code (super simple):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter"

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("aside",{"class":"portable-infobox pi-background pi-theme-mom pi-layout-default"})

for container in containers:
    name_container = containers.find("h2", {"class":"pi-item pi-item-spacing pi-title"})
```

This then results in an error stating:

```
"ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Which is odd, because I'm already using the `find()` function.

Even when I try to directly reference the specific tags through `containers` (see below), it still gives me the same error... And I'm not even using `find()` or `findAll()` this time!

```
for container in containers:
    name_container = containers.section.h2
```

Once again, this is not dealing with any form of table (that I can see), so I am really quite stumped as to why this error is being created. In fact, whenever I try to reference anything from `containers`, it gives me the same error.

*Any help or advice would be appreciated,
thanks.*

Comment: there is a typo in your code, you have used containers instead of container after for loop , change to `name_container = container.find("h2", {"class":"pi-item pi-item-spacing pi-title"})`

Comment: Awh man are you for real.... Thank you so much for that, I thought that was how it was meant to be annotated, but clearly I was mistaken. Again, thanks a lot, this can be closed now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8150371/stack) found a typo in my code, should have been referencing container instead of containers, like this:

```
name_container = container.find("h2", {"class":"pi-item pi-item-spacing pi-title"})
```

Cheers, [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8150371/stack).

Comment: If you solved the problem, you can mark your own answer as the answer for this question.